# MySQL seleccionar un valor máximo de un atributo en relación a cada posible valor que toma otro atributo

Tags: mysql, sql, distinct

Tengo una tabla con información demográfica y tengo que seleccionar tres columnas con continente, país y población que muestre el país con mayor población por continente. Entonces tengo que obtener 5 filas (5 continentes) y el país con mayor población por continente con su población.

Este es uno de mis intentos

```
SELECT continent, country, max(population)
FROM tabla_demo
WHERE continent in (
    SELECT distinct continent
    FROM tabla_demo);
```

Sin embargo creo que estoy más cerca con esta query si le añado un distinct para el continente o algo

```
SELECT continent, country, population
FROM tabla_demo
order by population desc
limit 5;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues nada más que decir que coincido con @Marco. Ahí va mi código de comprobación, por si pudiera aportar algo:

```
SELECT continent,country,population FROM (
    SELECT continent,MAX(population) population
      FROM tabla_demo GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 JOIN country USING(continent,population);
```

`USING` es el equivalente a `ON`, para aquellos casos en los que los nombres de los campos de las tablas del `JOIN` coinciden.

`GROUP BY 1` es para agrupar por el primer campo que aparece tras el `SELECT`, en este caso el equivalente sería `GROUP BY continent`

Comment: Se ve super cool tu consulta, voy a estudiar el `USING` y el `GROUP 1`, pero antes debo aclararte que el OP aclaró que la tabla que está usando es la de `tabla_demo` y no `country`, se equivocó.

Comment: Me alegra que te haya gustado: la corrijo y aprovecho para ampliar la respuesta con las aclaraciones sobre GROUP BY 1 y USING

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre una forma (que no me convence del todo) tal que primero haces una subconsulta que extrae la mayor población encontrada por cada continente de `tabla_demo`. Después haces un `JOIN` sobre esa consulta en los campos de continente y máxima población con la `tabla_demo` sobre los campos continente y población, y eso es para sacar el país.

```
SELECT
    max.continent,
    td.country,
    max.max_population
FROM (  SELECT
            continent,
            MAX(population) as 'max_population'
        FROM tabla_demo
        GROUP BY
            continent ) max
JOIN tabla_demo td
    ON max.continent = td.continent
    AND max.max_population = td.population
```

Cuya ejecución resulta en algo por este estilo, claramente con datos *dummy*, sólo para probar que al menos corre.

```
continent | country | max_population
------------------------------------
  America |  Brasil |              4
     Asia |   China |              4
   Africa | Argelia |              9
```

Comment: Perdonad pero al simplificar los nombres de atributos y demás para consultaros se me pasó uno y acabo de editar la primera query. Los tres valores a mostar están en única tabla llamada tabla_demo

Comment: @Cacu Claro, lo supuse. Que bueno que lo corregiste y que mal de mi parte no indicarlo o corregirlo yo. De todas maneras, la respuesta que te doy se basa en el nombre correcto de la tabla. Espero que sea de tu ayuda.